# Passing Arrays as Arguments

Tags: c#, arrays, arguments

In the following example, an array of strings is initialized and passed as an argument to a PrintArray method for strings. The method displays the elements of the array. Next, methods ChangeArray and ChangeArrayElement are called to demonstrate that sending an array argument by value does not prevent changes to the array elements.
My question is how the array didn't change in the method changeArray.. but changed in the method ChangeArrayElements?
here's the example:

```
class ArrayClass
{
    static void PrintArray(string[] arr)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
        {
            System.Console.Write(arr[i] + "{0}", i < arr.Length - 1 ? " " : "");
        }
        System.Console.WriteLine();
    }

    static void ChangeArray(string[] arr)
    {
        // The following attempt to reverse the array does not persist when 
        // the method returns, because arr is a value parameter.
        arr = (arr.Reverse()).ToArray();
        // The following statement displays Sat as the first element in the array.
        System.Console.WriteLine("arr[0] is {0} in ChangeArray.", arr[0]);
    }

     static void ChangeArrayElements(string[] arr)
    {
        // The following assignments change the value of individual array  
        // elements. 
        arr[0] = "Sat";
        arr[1] = "Fri";
        arr[2] = "Thu";
        // The following statement again displays Sat as the first element 
        // in the array arr, inside the called method.
        System.Console.WriteLine("arr[0] is {0} in ChangeArrayElements.", arr[0]);
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        // Declare and initialize an array. 
        string[] weekDays = { "Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat" };

        // Pass the array as an argument to PrintArray.
        PrintArray(weekDays);

        // ChangeArray tries to change the array by assigning something new 
        // to the array in the method. 
        ChangeArray(weekDays);

        // Print the array again, to verify that it has not been changed.
        System.Console.WriteLine("Array weekDays after the call to ChangeArray:");
        PrintArray(weekDays);
        System.Console.WriteLine();

        // ChangeArrayElements assigns new values to individual array 
        // elements.
        ChangeArrayElements(weekDays);

        // The changes to individual elements persist after the method returns. 
        // Print the array, to verify that it has been changed.
        System.Console.WriteLine("Array weekDays after the call to      ChangeArrayElements:");
        PrintArray(weekDays);
    } 
}
// Output:  
// Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat 
// arr[0] is Sat in ChangeArray. 
// Array weekDays after the call to ChangeArray: 
// Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat 
//  
// arr[0] is Sat in ChangeArrayElements. 
// Array weekDays after the call to ChangeArrayElements: 
// Sat Fri Thu Wed Thu Fri Sat
```

Comment: An array is a reference type  that contains variables accessed through indices. You're confusing variables and their values.

Comment: You should read: [Passing parameters in C# by Jon Skeet](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html)

Answer (score 2):

In this method:

```
static void ChangeArray(string[] arr)
{
    // The following attempt to reverse the array does not persist when 
    // the method returns, because arr is a value parameter.
    arr = (arr.Reverse()).ToArray();
    // The following statement displays Sat as the first element in the array.
    System.Console.WriteLine("arr[0] is {0} in ChangeArray.", arr[0]);
}
```

You are not changing the source array - you are creating a *new* array and saving the reference in the same variable.

Since the *reference* in `arr` is passed by value, the caller still has a reference to the original array - the fact that you have a *new* reference to the reversed array does not change the reference that the caller has.

By contract, in `ChangeArrayElements` you are changing the array that was passed in, so the caller sees those changes.

If the array reference was passed *by reference*:

```
static void ChangeArray(ref string[] arr)
{
    // Since 'arr' is passed by reference, changing the value of 'arr'
    // changes the reference that the caller has.
    arr = (arr.Reverse()).ToArray();
    // The following statement displays Sat as the first element in the array.
    System.Console.WriteLine("arr[0] is {0} in ChangeArray.", arr[0]);
}
```

Then the caller would see the change since you would be changing the reference that the caller is holding.

Here's a story (hopefully) illustrating the difference:

Passing reference types by value:

- `Main` - asks the universe for an array - universe tells it "the array is in slot 1".
- `Main` - writes a 1 on a sticky note labeled "weekDays"
- `Main` - tells `ChangeArray` that there is an array at slot 1.
- `ChangeArray` - writes down the number 1 on a sticky note labeled `arr`.
- `ChangeArray` - asks the universe to `Reverse` the array.  The universe reverses the array and tells `ChangeArray` that the new array is in slot 2.
- `ChangeArray` - crosses out the 1 on the sticky note labeled `arr` and writes a `2`.

As you can see, since `Reverse` does not change the original array, the array that the caller has a reference to does not change.

Passing reference types by reference:

- `Main` - asks the universe for an array - universe tells it "the array is in slot 1".
- `Main` - writes a 1 on a sticky note labeled "weekDays"
- `Main` - hands `ChangeArray` *the sticky note* with the number 1 on it.
- `ChangeArray` - asks the universe to `Reverse` the array.  The universe reverses the array and tells `ChangeArray` that the new array is in slot 2.
- `ChangeArray` - crosses out the 1 on the sticky note and writes a `2`.

In this case, the caller now has a *new* reference to the reversed array.  Since the *reference* ("sticky note") was passed instead of the *value* (the number on the note), the caller sees any changes to that reference.

Now let's look at `ChangeArrayElements`:

- `Main` - still has 1 on a sticky note labeled "weekDays"
- `Main` - tells `ChangeArrayElements` that there is an array at slot 1.
- `ChangeArrayElements` - writes down the number 1 on a sticky note labeled `arr`.
- `ChangeArrayElements` - changes in the values in the first three buckets of the array in slot 1.

Note that the difference here is that *the original array was modified*.  Since both the caller and function are looking at the same array, they both see the changes.

Comment: thank you, but why it has changed then in the other method changeArrayElements.. sorry I don't get it :(

Comment: @user3818372 because you're changing _the contents of the array_.  `Reverse` does not change the original array - it creates a _new_ array.  You just happen to save it in the same variable (which does not change the original reference.

Comment: yeah I got that thank you.. but I'm talking about the OTHER method.. changeArrayElements, what happened there?

Comment: That's what I'm talking about - you're changing the contents of the array:  `arr[0] = "Sat";`

Comment: but when I called the printArray method after changeArayElemrnt.. it prints the array changed.. didn't I pass it by value? how did it change then?

Comment: You passed the _reference_ to the array by value.  So changing the contents of the array is reflected in both places.